# Handling user activity on web portal with performance

Tags: database, performance, caching, scalability, sharding

The users on my website do operations like login, logout, update profile, change passwords etc. I am trying to come up with something that can store these user activities for my users and also return the matching records in case some system asks me for them based on userIds.

The problem from what I can think of looks more write intensive(since users keep logging into the website very often and I have to record that). Once in a while(say when users clicks on history or some reporting team needs it), the data records are read and returned.

So my application is write intensive

There are various approaches I can think of.
Approach 1. The system that gets those user activities keeps on writing them into a queue and another one keep fetching from that queue(periodically or when it is filled completely) and write them into database(which has been sharded(assume based on hash of userId)).

The problem with this approach is if my activity manager runs on multiple nodes, it has to send those records to various shards which means a lot of data movement over network.

Approach 2:The system that gets those user activities keeps on writing them into a queue and another one keep fetching from that queue(periodically or when it is filled completely) and write them into read though write through cache which would take care of writing into the database.

Problem with this approach is I do not know If I can control as to where those records would be written(I mean to which shard). Basically I do not know if the write through cache works(does it map to a local DB or it can manage to send data to shards).

Approach 3: The login operation is the most common user activity in my system. I can have a separate queue for login which must be periodically flushed to disk.

Approach 4: Use some cloud based storage which acts as a in memory queue where data coming from all nodes in stored. This would be reliable cache that guarantees no data loss. Periodically read from this cache and store that into the database shards.

There are many problems to solve:
1. Ensuring I do not loose the data(What kind of data replication to use i.e. any queue that ensures reliability)
2. Ensuring my frequent writes do not result in performance
3. Avoid single point of failure.
4. Achieving infinite scale

I need suggestion based on above from the existing solution available.